# Detecting complex shapes with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to see the difference between all 4 playing card symbols: heart, spade, diamond and club in real-time. This means that the angle, lighting, and distance to the symbol(s) constantly change (and therefore detecting objects based on contour area won't be an option).

So when I hold a heart symbol in front of my camera I'm trying to draw the word 'heart' inside it. if I do the same with a spade, I want it to write "spade", etc.

I have tried doing this in various different ways, but all attempts failed or didn't work as good as I want it to.

The methods I've tried:

- haarcascades
- template matching, doesn't work due to the rotations that are possible
- color detection, which only does half the job since there are 2 symbols per color
- feature matching: [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) doesn't work because the symbols don't have enough detail to find the keypoints

I can add source codes of these attempts if needed, but I don't think it will add any value, since they didn't really get me anywhere.

The Images I'm using:

[image]

Comment: have you succeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with relative low complex symbols why don't you try contour match shaping? You might have to adapt to some more complex cases but I think that could be a first good approach:

[Contours : More Functions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html)

[Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours)

Remember that you also have the color information to use in your app. Anyway, also take a look at [this](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/12/27/2d-curve-matching-in-opencv-w-code/).